# Ошибка при использовании сериализации

Tags: java

При компиляции мне выкидывает.

> Note: Main.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
>
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Как я понял, проблема в этом куске, но я не понял какая и как ее решить

```
try(FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(HISTORY_FILE)){
        try(ObjectInputStream historyIn = new ObjectInputStream (fileIn)){
            history = (ArrayList<Settings>) historyIn.readObject();     
        }
        catch(IOException ex){}
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){}
    }
    catch(IOException ex){}
```

Comment: это не ошибка - предупреждение. и вам компилятор говорит номер строки.

Answer (score 1):

Так как вы десериализуете объект из потока, то компилятор не может проверить его тип о чем вам и сообщает. Вы можете убрать это предупреждение используя аннотацию

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

Поставьте эту аннотацию перед методом, где вы получаете объект из потока.